# For each loop value not being sent to subsequent function. What is happening here? Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, loops, foreach

I have been working on this project for three days now and I am almost to the point where I understand everything that I am doing and why a value is throwing an error, but in this code:

```
function updateStats(){
    const users = readFile('users','txt','UTF-8');
    users.forEach((v) => {    
        console.log(v);
        var user =  v.toString();
        const statFile = readFile(user,'txt','UTF-8');
        readHTTP(v,currentChannel,statFile[0]);
    });
}
```

Throws the error:

```
I am doing my 15 minutes update
610636905440215071
677257430249242655
539899963568553986
525819952708583427
373982165307752460

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/codel/OneDrive/Documents/BattlEye/files/.txt'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:476:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:377:35)
    at readFile (C:\Users\codel\OneDrive\Documents\BattlEye\index.js:98:25)
    at C:\Users\codel\OneDrive\Documents\BattlEye\index.js:214:26
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at updateStats (C:\Users\codel\OneDrive\Documents\BattlEye\index.js:211:11)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\codel\OneDrive\Documents\BattlEye\index.js:27:3)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/Users/codel/OneDrive/Documents/BattlEye/files/.txt'
}
C:\Users\codel\OneDrive\Documents\BattlEye\index.js:215
        readHTTP(v,currentChannel,statFile[0]);
                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at C:\Users\codel\OneDrive\Documents\BattlEye\index.js:215:43
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at updateStats (C:\Users\codel\OneDrive\Documents\BattlEye\index.js:211:11)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\codel\OneDrive\Documents\BattlEye\index.js:27:3)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the function structure, but my other foreach loops run just fine in this syntax. Could someone help debug this?

Edit:
Read File:

```
function readFile(fileName,fileType,fileFormat){
    try {
        const data = fs.readFileSync('/Users/codel/OneDrive/Documents/BattlEye/files/'+fileName+'.'+fileType, fileFormat);
        const lines = data.split(/\r?\n/);
        return lines;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

ReadHTTP:

```
function readHTTP(user,cc,userID){
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    var url= 'https://r6.tracker.network/profile/pc/' + userID;
    (async() => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        try {
        await page.goto(url);
        } catch(error){
            cc.send('You did not enter a valid Ubisoft UserID');
        }
        const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
            return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.trn-defstat__value'))
                    .map(item => item.innerText);
        }); 
        writeStatFile(user,userID,data);
        console.log("Personal stats file was written");
    })();
}
```

I just learned this language two days ago, but the value is not passing through the for each loop to the subsequent function.

Comment: It looks like as it can't read the file `users`, you can't run forEach() on `users`. Check the filename you are trying to read.

Comment: @Ozgur Sar I added an edit with the full log. It reads users.txt but when searching for the *user*.txt file the value is not being sent. The full log shows the console.log(v) is outputting the values I need.

Comment: Please post the code of `readFile` (and possibly `readHTTP`), we can't help you without that.

Comment: Use a debugger and check what the value of `v`/`user` is. My bet: your `users.txt` ends with a newline, and the last `v` is the empty string.

Comment: @Bergi I think your'e right. The way I am reading the file pertains to split each line. You were right. It was simply an uncaught blankspace.

Comment: Ah, my crystal ball is still working :-) Btw you should also omit the `catch (err) {  console.error(err); }`. It causes your function to return `undefined`, which the caller doesn't want to deal with. Don't use `try`/`catch` in a function if you cannot actually *handle* the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost entirely certain you have an empty newline in `users.txt`

I would do the following:

```js
function updateStats(){
    const users = readFile('users','txt','UTF-8');
    users.forEach((v) => {
        if (v === '') return
        console.log(v);
        var user =  v.toString();
        const statFile = readFile(user,'txt','UTF-8');
        readHTTP(v,currentChannel,statFile[0]);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> errno: -4058,
> syscall: 'open',
> code: 'ENOENT',
> path: '/Users/codel/OneDrive/Documents/BattlEye/files/.txt' <-- I think the error comes from this...

A good reason to look for is asynchrony issues.

try this:

```
const promises = require('fs').promises

const updateStats = async () => {
  try {
    const users = await promises.readFile('users.txt', {encoding: 'utf8'});
    for (let user of users.split("\n")) {
      const statFile = await promises.readFile(user.toString() + '.txt', {encoding: 'utf8'});

      if(statFile && statFile[0]) {
        readHTTP(user,currentChannel,statFile[0]);
      }
    }
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err.toString())
  }
}
```

Not sure if this is will work, as I did not have time to test it.

Really hope this helps :)